# How to change Dateformat in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need to change the date format (dateFrom) in the following (Tag) xml.

*change by: dd/mm /yyyy

```
<CancellationPolicies>
        <CancellationPolicy amount="355.500" dateFrom="20140613" time="2359" />
</CancellationPolicies>
```

For that I use this xslt: What to add in the xslt?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ServiceHotel/AvailableRoom/HotelRoom/RoomType">
      Política de cancelación: Tipo Hab.
      <xsl:value-of select="@characteristic"/>
      codigo:
      <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="//CancellationPolicies/CancellationPolicy">
      Si cancelas después de las
      <xsl:value-of select="@time"/>
      PM del
      <xsl:value-of select="@dateFrom"/>
      se aplicaran unos gastos de:
      <xsl:value-of select="@amount"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="//*/Currency/@code"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date and time conversions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416944/date-and-time-conversions)

Comment: There are no date formats in XSLT 1.0. This is a question in string manipulation.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you give me an example?

```
<xsl:template match="CancellationPolicy">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@dateFrom, 7, 2), '/', substring(@dateFrom, 5, 2), '/', substring(@dateFrom, 1, 4))"/>
</xsl:template>
```